# Video with speed (from GPS log)

Tags: video, speed, gps

is there any way to log GPS information on Android and then put it into video which shows speed? Something like this [Brno circuit onboard video](http://youtu.be/cAIu4rHnYuc?t=29s)

I have an Android device where I want to log speed and camera (for example a GoPro) where I want to capture video.

Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will be searching for overlaying GPS information, or telemetry in general on videos, so here's one commercial solution that does this, which is often referenced:

[DashWare](http://www.dashware.net/)

[image]

Also check out this blog article: [How-To: Video Overlays with GPS Data](http://inlinepaceline.wordpress.com/2012/04/22/how-to-video-overlays-with-gps-data/), which explains how to overlay [Garmin TCX and GPX](https://sites.google.com/site/verymadmart/cyclecam) files onto video.

Comment: Thank You very much :) This was exactly what I needed :)